# Steam - Remote download on free games?

Tags: steam

So, sometimes when you buy a game on a phone or tablet and not a computer, it gives you the option to "remote download" the game. If Steam is running in the background, it will download the game you bought. As far as I know, it only works on paid games, but is there a way to remote download a free game?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I tried with Fallout Shelter, but it just asked if I had Steam installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. To install the game remotely it needs to be listed [here](http://steamcommunity.com/my/games?tab=all). If it's not, you need to start download on the computer you have Steam installed.

I've tried to simulate what "remote download" button does but for games that never were in your library it fails and returns different code.

Fun fact: Click `Play Game` on store page, click `Yes, Steam is installed`, cancel download window and from now you can download that game remotely. <sub>At least works for Fallout Shelter</sub>

Comment: So then how do I add a free game to my library on mobile

Comment: You can't. At least I haven't found any way to do it.